# How can I scrape the member count of Facebook groups into a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get the number of members of some Facebook groups. I tried to play with the Facebook Graph API but it does not work:

```
function facebook(url) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.facebook.com/groups/449592401822610/?ref=br_rs');
var object = Utilities.jsonParse(jsondata.getContentText());
return object.shares;
}
```

Is it possible to do that?
Thanks for your help

[UPDATE]
Sometimes I don't have the ID of the group. I wrote this to solve the issue but it does not work...

```
function facebook(group) {
  if (isNaN(group) == true) {
    var jsondata1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='+group+'&type=group&access_token={my token}');
    var object1 = Utilities.jsonParse(jsondata1.getContentText());
    var id = object1.data.id;

    var jsondata2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/'+id+'/members?summary=true&access_token={my token}');
    var object2 = Utilities.jsonParse(jsondata2.getContentText());
    return object2.summary.total_count;
  }
  else {
    var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/'+group+'/members?summary=true&access_token={my token}');
    var object = Utilities.jsonParse(jsondata.getContentText());
    return object.summary.total_count;
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Graph API

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/449592401822610/members?summary=true&access_token={user-access_token}
```

you will get response like this if it is closed group

```
{
 "data": [

],
"summary": {
  "total_count": 4113
}
}
```

and if it is public group you will also receive members detail in **data** section

Good Luck

NOTE: this will only return count <5000 member. If your group is near 5000 or more than 5000 it will return 4897, 4756, or some other "random" number, but will never return more than 5000.

Comment: I still have an issue, sometimes in my list I don't have the ID of the group but his name. I tried to write a function to get the ID but it does not work, do you see where I have a mistake? Thanks (see Update of the question)

Comment: returned data is a array..
so 
var id = object1.data[0].id;

Comment: Ayy sorry, thanks a lot, now everything is working ;) Have a good day!

Comment: sometime it happens :P

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL in your code is wrong, I'm guessing it should be

```
http://graph.facebook.com/groups/449592401822610/?ref=br_rs
```

Comment: Thanks, when I enter this URL in my web browser I get:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "DAUjkZeHqRr"
   }
}

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the access token to the URL